# How to find a products parent in sales order

Tags: magento

I am getting following information using the order number.
How can I find that for a product parent type product was bundle product?

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app("default");

$orderNumber = 260038;  
    
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderNumber);

    // get order item collection
$orderItems = $order->getItemsCollection();

    
    $skuQtyArray = array();
    foreach ($orderItems as $item)
    {   
       $product_id = $item->product_id;
          //**How to find here if above product's parent was a bundle product**

    }       
    
    
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check from this way

```
<?php
    require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
    umask(0);
    Mage::app("default");

    $orderNumber = 260038;  

    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderNumber);

    // get order item collection
    $orderItems = $order->getItemsCollection();


    $skuQtyArray = array();
    foreach ($orderItems as $item)
    {   
        $product_id = $item->product_id;
        $_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
        if ($_product->getTypeId() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_BUNDLE) {

            echo 'Bundled';//Do your stuf here
        }
        //**How to find here if above product's parent was a bundle product**

    }       


?>
```

Comment: How do I get the SKU of bundle selection item? I ma able to get values like

 [45716] => Array
                (
                    [option_id] => 45716
                    [label] => Optional Pieces
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [title] => En Vogue  Floor Mirror 
                                    [qty] => 1
                                    [price] => 349
                                )

                        )

                )

Comment: could you please suggest some idea for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716335/how-do-i-get-bundle-option-selection-sku